# Closing ASP menu when moving mouse

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, aspmenu

I'm working with a project that has as ASP menu (), which I can't get to close. All I want it to do is to collapse when the mouse is not hovering it. Is there a setting or something to fix this? Maybe a simple problem but I've searched everywhere with no luck.

I can expand the menu just fine, and when I move to a different node it switches to that just. The problem is when I move the mouse outside the entire menu, it stays open. Shouldn't there be some simple setting for this? Do I really have to jump through several hoops of javascript and events to fix this?

Comment: add javascript blur/focus event hooks to expand/close the menu?

Comment: I'm kind of a beginner so I'm looking into that. But this problem seems to be too simple. Feels like there just some dumb setting.

Answer (score 0):

By default, menu should collapse as soon as cursor is out. Strip out all css and test it with simple code.

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MenuTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2012.MenuTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Menu runat="server" DataSourceID="MenuDataSource"></asp:Menu>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="MenuDataSource" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false"
            SiteMapProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>

// MenuTest.sitemap
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="Home" title="Home"  description="Home">
        <siteMapNode url="Monday" title="One"  description="One" >
          <siteMapNode url="Monday - One" title="Monday - One" description="Monday - One" />
          <siteMapNode url="Monday - Two" title="Monday - Two" description="Monday - Two" />
          <siteMapNode url="Monday - Three" title="Monday - Three" description="Monday - Three" />
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="Tuesday" title="Tuesday"  description="Tuesday" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>

// web.config    
<system.web>
  ...
  <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/MenuTest.sitemap" />
    </providers>
  </siteMap>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Tried removing all CSS styling but it didn't work. It's generated from a database so maybe that plays a part somehow.